# Memory Leaks In Linux Process

Tags: linux, memory-leaks, process, heap-memory

I have a process I'm running,
and from watching the /Proc//Status I get the following:

Every 1.0s: cat /proc/23165/status                                                                                                 Sun Jan 17 20:31:49 2016

```
Name:   sqreamd
State:  S (sleeping)
Tgid:   23165
Pid:    23165
PPid:   24976
TracerPid:      0
Uid:    501     501     501     501
Gid:    501     501     501     501
Utrace: 0
FDSize: 256
Groups: 501
VmPeak: 81441688 kB
VmSize: 81343268 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmHWM:    687308 kB
VmRSS:    683144 kB
VmData: 80379996 kB
VmStk:       540 kB
VmExe:       764 kB
VmLib:    417260 kB
VmPTE:      8336 kB
VmSwap:        0 kB
Threads:        12
SigQ:   2/256227
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
ShdPnd: 0000000000000000
SigBlk: 0000000000000000
SigIgn: 0000000000000000
SigCgt: 0000000182081002
CapInh: 0000000000000000
CapPrm: 0000000000000000
CapEff: 0000000000000000
CapBnd: ffffffffffffffff
Cpus_allowed:   ff
Cpus_allowed_list:      0-7
Mems_allowed:   00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,0000
0001
```

I'm looking at VMSize which is increasing, but is it the right parameter to look at?

Eventually what happens is the process dies and I'm trying to get a lead on anything, so any tip would be useful.

Comment: I there a question here?

Comment: VMSize [appears to be](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) total process size.  Use caution with the term "memory leak," though -- a process can have an appetite for a lot of memory without technically "leaking" it, which is a term only properly applied to code that neglects to release memory that it no longer needs and will never access again through any possible code branch as long as it is running.  You can't tell the difference, from here, between a leak and a program that simply has an increasing workload-related demand for memory.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks for your comment.